# Passing a reverse route as a JavaScript parameter in Scala Play

Tags: ajax, scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm using reverse routing within AJAX to call an Action from a controller in my view:

```
<script>
                function loadDoc() {
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("toolOptions").innerHTML =
                                    this.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    xhttp.open("GET", "@routes.MyController.loadTemplate2()", true);
                    xhttp.send();
                }
        </script>
```

and my controller at app.controllers.MyController has a method:

```
def loadTemplate2() = Action {
    implicit request: Request[AnyContent] => Ok(views.html.template2())
  }
```

Which is routed like:

`GET     /mycontroller/retrieve2        controllers.MyController.loadTemplate2`

And when I hardcode the route like this and call it from somewhere in the template like `<li onclick="loadDoc()">Load Template 2</li>`, it works as expected and loads the template 2. However, this method is useful, and I want to be able to parameterize the URL called by the `xhttp.open`, so I want to replace

`function loadDoc()` with `function loadDoc(myURL)` and

`xhttp.open("GET", "@routes.MyController.loadTemplate2()", true);` with 
`xhttp.open("GET", myUrl, true);`

And then be able to call other methods I may have, say:

```
def loadTemplate3() = Action {
    implicit request: Request[AnyContent] => Ok(views.html.template2())
  }
```

From somewhere else in the template from a `<li>` like:

```
<li onclick="loadDoc(@routes.MyController.loadTemplate2())">Load Template 2</li>
<li onclick="loadDoc(@routes.MyController.loadTemplate3())">Load Template 3</li>
```

But when I do this, it doesn't work. The console tells me
SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag d

I've also tried to do this instead

`<li onclick="loadDoc(@routes.MyController.loadTemplate2())">Load Template 2.absoluteURL(true)</li>`

But this tells me SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Learn More] in the console. The error message points to a line in the header of the generated HTML (1:13), which doesn't make any sense - there aren't ANY "()"'s up there . But I've changed nothing else and can't spot any missing ')' anywhere. I feel like I'm close, but can't quite get it.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified this question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193360/how-to-feed-a-url-with-a-to-a-javascript-object), and the answers are taken from two of the responders:

There are two issues. I am trying to pass a String literal, and the

```
@routes.MyController.loadTemplate2()
```

Turns into something like this in the rendered HTML `/theUrl/toTheServer`

Problem is, starting something with `/` is indication that you're going to use a Regex.

Change this:

```
<li onclick="loadDoc(@routes.MyController.loadTemplate2())">Load Template 2</li>
```

to

```
<li onclick="loadDoc('@routes.MyController.loadTemplate2()')">Load Template 2</li>
```

or

```
<li onclick="loadDoc(&quot;@routes.MyController.loadTemplate2()&quot;)">Load Template 2</li>
```

Comment: Just a side note: When using play reverse routing, you'll get a `play.api.mvc.Call` (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Call) instance back. So when you're embedding this into your template, I'd suggest to manually extract the url from the `Call`. That way you're not depending on the `toString` implementation on the `Call` class.