# How to feed a URL with a / to a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a simple AJAX/JavaScript function which makes a GET request and loads a page into the current page based on a URL if successful:

```
function loadDoc(myUrl) {
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("toolOptions").innerHTML =
                                    this.responseText;
                        }
                    };

                    xhttp.open("GET", myUrl, true);
                    xhttp.send();
 }
```

And I'm calling the function later on in the same document with this:

`<li onclick="loadDoc(/myUrl/toTheLocalSever)">Add Dataset to View</li>`

(the URL is generated by Scala Play's reverse routing, but this is exactly how it renders in the final source - so I don't think Play is the issue here).

But, whenever I do this, I get this in my console:

`SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag d`

I thought it was an issue with the quotes, so I did this in the original function `loadDoc(myUrl)`:

```
var wrappedUrl = "'"+myUrl+"'"
xhttp.open("GET", wrappedUrl, true);
```

But that still gives me the same error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The value of the attribute needs to evaluate to valid JavaScript. You have forgotten to include quotes around your string. These sorts of issues are why you should *never* add JavaScript via attributes.

Comment: You need to add the quotes at the time scala produces it. No idea about scala, but you'll need to quote the producer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought it was an issue with the quotes

It is.

You are trying to write a string literal without any.

```
onclick="loadDoc(&quot;/myUrl/toTheLocalSever&quot;)">
```

> ```
> var wrappedUrl = "'"+myUrl+"'"
> ```

You can't fix a syntax error from code that runs after the error has been thrown.

Comment: That definitely did it. I've spent so many hours on this, thank you. Perhaps it's Play, but it would tell me the error was occurring way up in the head of the document, instead of at `function loadDoc(myUrl) {` where one would think the error would first be picked up.

Comment: The error occurs at `loadDoc(/myUrl/toTheLocalSever)"`. It fails to parse the regular expression literal. It has nothing to do with the loadDoc function. That never gets called because the syntax error gets thrown first.

Comment: Ah, good to note. Sorry - I am new to AJAX and JS and more comfortable with Java/Scala. Still same thing though, `loadDoc(/myUrl/toTheLocalSever)"` is way further down the doc, at about line 73 or so, but the error throws at line 26.

Answer (score 1):

i believe the error is in your function call

```
<li onclick="loadDoc(/myUrl/toTheLocalSever)">Add Dataset to View</li>
```

should be

```
<li onclick="loadDoc('/myUrl/toTheLocalSever')">Add Dataset to View</li>
```

in your version its passing <strike>as variable</strike> /myUrl/toTheLocalSever which <strike>does not exist</strike> is regular expression syntax

Comment: `/myUrl/toTheLocalSever` is not a variable. A `/` character indicates the start of a regular expression literal (but the suffix is invalid so it errors)

Comment: I wish I could also mark this answer as accepted, as it works just as well. Especially after your edit.